# Algorithm to detect if 2 cuboid are colliding giving their bounds

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have 4 positions, with X, Y and Z component. The first 2 vectors represent the 2 extents, and the other vector represent the other 2 extents of the other cuboid.

An example:

```
Vector3 firstCubeMax = Vector3(10, 10, 10);
Vector3 firstCubeMin = Vector3(-10, -10, -10);
Vector3 secondCubeMax = Vector3(0, 0, 0);
Vector3 secondCubeMin = Vector3(-30, -60, -30);
```

(first cuboid starts at 0,0,0 with size (20,20,20). The second one starts at (15, 30, 15) and has a size of (30,60,30))

What I want to do is to check if 2 cuboids are colliding (touching or going through) giving those vectors. Also, I am using C++

Comment: What do you mean by a cube having a `size of (30, 60, 30)`?  You are then talking about a cuboid.

Comment: @Tawnos Nothing, don't know how to start

Comment: @Shredderroy Fixed, sorry.

Comment: The way you define your cuboid: do you mean it's a cube with a given space diagonal and its edges parallel to the axis? I cannot see how else you can define them unambiguously given the information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the right side of one cuboid is before the left side of other, or the top of one cuboid is below the bottom of the other, or the front of one cuboid is behind the back of the other, then they do not intersect. Otherwise, they do.

So negate the "ors" into a bunch of "ands" to get:

```
return firstCubeMin.x() < secondCubeMax.x()
    && secondCubeMin.x() < firstCubeMax.x()
    && firstCubeMin.y() < secondCubeMax.y()
    && secondCubeMin.y() < firstCubeMax.y()
    && firstCubeMin.z() < secondCubeMax.z()
    && secondCubeMin.z() < firstCubeMax.z()
```

Put another way, they intersect if and only if they intersect when projected onto all three axes. The "only if" direction is obvious; you can prove the "if" direction by thinking about what it means for a point to be inside a cuboid.